# prepareForDeletion being called once when I call deleteObject: and a second time when I save

Tags: ios, core-data, cs193p

edited with extra information:
I am using an app based on `CoreDataTableViewController` from cs193p.
When I delete an instance of an entity called `Position`, the `prepareForDeletion` is called immediately. But when I call `saveToURL`, or when the database is being autosaved, `prepareForDeletion` is called again.

Is this the way it should be? can I prevent it?

Comment: Are using a background thread?

Comment: I am only using the main thread

Comment: did you have found a solution?

Comment: I'm using a background thread @LorenzoB :D is this issue solved, 5 years later.. :)

Comment: Bringing back the issue from the dead...I don't remember what I did eventually, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Set a `BOOL isDeleting` and check to see if the process is already being ran.

### Example

```
- (void) prepareForDeletion
{
    if ( isDeleting ) 
        return;


    /* handle the rest of the deleting process */
    isDeleting = YES;


    if ( /* the process has finished deleting */ )
        isDeleting = NO;
}
```

Comment: this will not work. since the first prepareForDeletion is completed before the second one start. and it is also bypassing the problem, not really solving it I think

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the way it should be. UIManagedDocument uses two ManagedObjectContexts. When the child context (document.managedObjectContext) saves, it does so to its parent context. The objects in the parent context will in turn have their `prepareForDeletion` called immediately when the parent saves to the persistent store.